# How "much" does (Grigorieff) forcing destroy an ultrafilter?

Tags: ultrafilters, forcing, set-theory

**Introduction.** I recently revisited Shelah's model without P-points and I was wondering how "badly" Grigorieff forcing destroys ultrafilters, i.e., what kind of properties can survive the destruction of the "ultra"ness.

**An example.** Given a free (ultra)filter $F$ on $\omega$, **Grigorieff forcing** is defined as
$$ G(F) := \{ f:X \rightarrow 2:  \omega \setminus X \in F \},$$
partially ordered by reverse inclusion. A simple density argument shows that **"$G(F)$ destroys $F$"**, i.e., the filter generated by $F$ in a generic extension is **not** an ultrafilter (the generic real being the culprit).

Of course, there are many forcing notions that specifically destroy ultrafilters (also, Bartoszynski, Judah and Shelah showed that whenever there's a new real in the extension, some ground model ultrafilter was destroyed).

My question is:

**If $F$ is destroyed, how far away is $F$ from being the ultrafilter it once was?**

Maybe a more positive version: **Which properties of $F$ can we destroy while preserving others?**

This might seem awfully vague, so before you vote to close let me explain what kind of answers I'm hoping for.

- **Positive answers.**

  - If the forcing is $\omega^\omega$-bounding and $F$ is rapid, then $F$ will still be rapid. That's a very clean and simple preservation.
  - In Shelah's model without P-points, all ground model Ramsey ultrafilters stop being P-points but "remain" Q-points.
- **"Minimal" answers.** Is it possible that $F$ together with the generic real generates an ultrafilter, i.e., there are only two ultrafilters extending $F$? For Grigorieff forcing, I'd expect this needs at least a Ramsey ultrafilter. But maybe other forcings have this property?
- **Negative answers.** Say $F$ is a P-point; can $F$ still be extended to a P-point? Shelah tells us that forcing with the full product $G(F)^\omega$ denies this. Is it known whether $G(F)$ already denies this? Do other forcing notions allow this?

I know there is a lot of literature on **preserving ultrafilters** (mostly P-points, I think) but I'm more interested in the case where the ultrafilter is actually destroyed. But I'd welcome anything that sheds light on this.

PS: community wiki, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a proof that, if $F$ is an ultrafilter and $g$ is $F$-Grigorieff-generic, then $F\cup\{g\}$ does not generate an ultrafilter in the extension.  Define a real $x:\omega\to2$ (also viewed as $x\subseteq\omega$ as usual) by letting $x(n)=\sum_{k=0}^ng(k)$ modulo 2.  (Technically, I should fix the obvious names for $g$ and $x$, but for simplicity let me omit the resulting dots over the letters.)  Suppose, toward a contradiction, that $x$ or its complement is in the filter generated by $F\cup\{g\}$.  Then there is a condition $p$ and there is a set $B\in F$ such that either (1) $p$ forces $B\cap g\subseteq x$ or (2) $p$ forces $B\cap g\subseteq\omega-x$.  Fix two numbers $a<b$ such that neither of them is in the domain of $p$ and such that $b\in B$.  (This can be done because $B$ is in $F$ while the domain of $p$ isn't.)  Now form two extensions $q$ and $q'$ of $p$ as follows.  Both of them have the value 1 at $b$ (so they force $b\in g$ and therefore $b\in B\cap g$); they are both defined at $a$ but take opposite values there; and they are both defined and equal at all other numbers smaller than $b$.  Then one of them forces $b\in x$ and the other forces $b\notin x$.  This is absurd, as both extend $p$, which already decided between (1) (which will require $b\in x$) and (2) (which will require $b\notin x$).

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It's a wonderful general argument that I can keep in mind.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to add two comments that I received in 'meatspace'. I hope this isn't too inappropriate.

- If $F$ is a P-filter, and the forcing is proper, than $F$ generates a P-filter in the extension.
- If $F$ is a Q-filter, i.e., every finite-to-one map becomes injective on a set in $F$, and the forcing is $\omega^\omega$-bounding, then $F$ generates a Q-filter in the extension.

Proofs of these facts can be found, e.g., in [Shelah, Proper and Improper Forcing, Chapter VI, Section 4 and 5 resp.](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Proper-and-Improper-Forcing/toc/pl/1235419814)

One more example from myself.

- If $F$ is an [idempotent filter](https://refubium.fu-berlin.de/discover?filtertype_0=mycoreId&filter_relational_operator_0=equals&filter_0=FUDISS_derivate_000000006649) then $F$ will remain an idempotent filter in any forcing extension. In particular, if $F$ is an idempotent ultrafilter, it will still extend to an idempotent ultrafilter.

Comment: @Will: What's "metaspace"? (I understand what "meatspace" is supposed to mean.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I don't know what either word means. I thought that "metaspace" sounded like a thing, and the sort of place where one might find interesting mathematical results. I thought "meatspace" sounded like not a thing (and a kind of gross would-be thing) and assumed it was a typo. I guess I should have googled "meatspace" to check on that before editing the post. Now that I have googled it, I think "meatspace" was deliberate.

Comment: @Will: Meatspace clearly refers to "in person". It's the space where meat lives, as opposed to the virtual space, where only virtual things live and these are traditionally vegan.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: https://vegfaqs.com/are-electronics-vegan/#Some_Electronics_May_Have_Animal_Products_in_Them

Comment: @Will: Unfortunately, electronics live in meatspace. They host the virtual space, yes, but they live in meatspace.

Comment: @WillBrian "Meatspace" for the real world, in opposition to "cyberspace" was popularized by William Gibson in his science fiction novels, *e.g.* Neuromancer. [He disclaims inventing the term.](https://twitter.com/greatdismal/status/171998023830863872) It then became a commonly-used hacker retronym, like "snail mail" for ordinary mail (in contradistinction to e-mail).